# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_33 has terminated

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device, null-terminated

## 'Android Studio

## Fix Error: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_33 has terminated??

## You need choose the version **System Image** under 13!

## Follow the pictures below in sequence:

## [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrnXM.png)

## [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGuHa.png)

## [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiVDK.png)

## [Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt3f3.png)

## The power of share!'